# Typescript react-redux connect type question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

### Code

App.tsx

```
function App(){
return(
  <>
    <Slider products={products} />.  // Error
  </>
}
export default App;
```

Slider.tsx

```
import { useSelector, connect } from "react-redux";
import { ProductType, ProductItem, StateType } from "types";
const Slider = ({ products, number }: any) => {
//  const number = useSelector((state: StateType) => state.number);
  return (
    <S.Slider>
         <S.SliderWrapper widthSize={number}>
           {products}
             ...
         <S.SliderWrapper>
    </S.Slider>
  );
};

export default connect((state: any) => {
  console.log(state.number);
  return { number: state.number };
}, null)(Slider);
```

type.ts

```
export interface ProductItem {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  bgcolor: string;
  colors: { code: string; img: any }[];
}
export interface ProductType {
  products: ProductItem[];
}
```

Currently, Slider Component is using useSelector, but an error occurs when trying to change it to connect. So, how should I change the connect part and how should I modify the parameter and type of the slider component?

### Error Message

> TS2322: Type '{ products: { id: number; title: string; price: number;
> bgcolor: string; colors: { code: string; img: any; }[]; }[]; }' is not
> assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<any, string | number |
> symbol>'.   Property 'products' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<any, string | number | symbol>'.

### Solution

Slider.tsx

```
const Slider = ({ number, products }: any) => {
   ...
   ...
}
export default connect((state: StateType, { products }: ProductType) => {
  return { number: state.number, products };
}, null)(Slider);
```

Comment: Please take the [tour]. We don't mark questions as [solved]. Also see [ask] and revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Your solution is in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71048361/revisions) in case you need it to post an answer.